# Javascript: which 'time processing' function is faster?

Tags: javascript, performance

I just created two versions of a function that can be used to process the date and time and return it to different HTML elements. These elements will be displayed a phone lockscreen. The function is called every second, to make sure it jumps to the next minute in time.

- v.1 works at once: it processes every time unit (sec., min. day, month etc.) each second.
- v.2 works step by step: if the numbers of second is at any time "0" process the minutes. Then, if minutes is "0" process the hours etc.

I'd expected v.2 to be faster, but according to a test I did here: http://jsperf.com/timecalccompare it's about 90% slower! *Is* it really slower or is the test unreliable?

Comment: This is why the 97% is usually "good enough" ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the simpler way, but additionally check if the minute has actually changed before updating the view and doing the rest of the calculations:

Also there's absolutely no reason to declare the months and days array on each iteration, so:

```
var months      = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var days        = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var lastMinute = null;

function Update()
{
    var now, minutes, hours, day, date, month, daypart = "AM";
    now         = new Date();
    minutes     = now.getMinutes();
    if(minutes == lastMinute) return;
    hours       = now.getHours();
    day         = days[now.getDay()];
    date        = now.getDate();
    month       = months[now.getMonth()].substring(0, 3);

    if(minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if(hours > 12) {
        hours -= 12;
        daypart = "PM";
    }
    if(hours == 0) hours = 12;

    $("#clock").text(hours + ":" + minutes + " " + daypart);
    $("#day").text(day);
    $("#date").text(date + " " + month);
    lastMinute = minutes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Though can you explain why the step by step script takes so long? The idea is that it breaks immediately when e.g. the number of seconds isn't zero. Clearly, it doesn't...

Comment: Hmm... oddly, your function is reported as 75% slower. This doesn't make much sense :P

Comment: Heh... I just realized that the JSPerf tests don't even actually run the functions at all, so the measurements are totally bogus. So declaring my function over and over again is 75% slower for some reason. ;P http://jsperf.com/timecalccompare/3 has an updated version comparing my version and your version 1. (However, I took out the minute comparison from my code to make the test sane and fair.)

Comment: Great! I think I'm going to your version, probably with the minute check.

Answer (score 0):

Your second version is just broken and doesn't do anything remotely approaching what it's supposed to do. If incrementing the seconds doesn't leave them at zero, you need to *stop* processing, not keep doing a bunch more tests.

Answer (score 0):

advise：try to reduce the number of DOM access

your step by step script is not working!